# Cocoa library for popup with different title from value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking for the best approach to this issue. I have a PopUp Button with 4 entries in it. I would like the user to be able to change them, however when the popup button changes and I access the selected value, it will be my predefined value and not what they customized it to be.

**Example**

```
|Value1|
|Value2|
|Value3|
|Value4|
```

is my predefined. They may change them to

```
|1Value|
|2Value|
|3Value|
|4Value|
```

However when they select `3Value` I need the code to see `Value3`.

Is there an already existing library that supports this? If not what would be the best approach to do something like this? This is for a Mac OS X Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using coredata with a `apieKey` and `displayValue`. I then use a fetch request to get the key (original value) when needed.

Answer (score 1):

In `NSPopUpButton` you will find a property `indexOfItem`. Just use the index to identify the items.

```
NSArray *original = // the values of the original items 
NSInteger *selected = [popUpButton indexOfItem:popUpButton.selectedItem];
id originalItem = [original objectAtIndex:selected];
```

Comment: this should work, however one concern is what if we do sorting of the edited items?

Comment: That is another issue entirely. You can change the order of items dynamically in your data model by making the `original` array mutable.